# Print. Como editar todo en fila?

Tags: python-3.x

BD

Aqui me encuentro con una situacion.

quiero hacer una salida con el print para poder mostrar los equipos seleccionados.

de esta forma:

```
Grupo A    GrupoB  GrupoC
pais1      pais3   pais5
pais2      pais4   pais6
```

aqui les pongo el trozo de codigo.
He leido algo sobre end = '', pero no me hace lo que deseo. lo añado y lo que hace es correrme el nombre del grupo y lo pone al lado del ultimo resultado. no quisiera tener que hacer una edicion a mano.
el codigo que les muestro trata primero sobre una lista de paises que van a participar en el campeonato, despues voy seleccionando los grupos de 4, hasta que al final solo quedan 8 grupos de 4, pues son 32 paises.

```
import random

print('Estos son los paises que participan en el mundial de futbol...')
print()
paises1 =['Rusia','Egipto','Arabia Saudí','Uruguay','Portugal','España','Marruecos','Irán','Francia','Australia',
            'Perú','Dinamarca','Argentina','Islandia','Croacia','Nigeria','Brasil','Suiza','Costa Rica','Serbia',
        'Alemania','México','Suecia','Corea del Sur','Bélgica','Panamá','Túnez','Inglaterra','Polonia','Senegal',
        'Colombia','Japón']
print(paises1)
print()
print('...se procede a realizar el sorteo...')

bolsa1 = []
bolsa2 = []
bolsa3 = []
bolsa4 = []
bolsa5 = []
bolsa6 = []
bolsa7 = []
bolsa8 = []


i = j = k = l = m = n = o = 1

while i<5:
    i+=1
    a = random.choice(range(len(paises1)))


    bolsa1.append(paises1[a])
    paises1.pop(a)

    while j<5:
        j+=1
        a = random.choice(range(len(paises1)))

        bolsa2.append(paises1[a])
        paises1.pop(a)

        while k<5:
            k+=1
            a = random.choice(range(len(paises1)))

            bolsa3.append(paises1[a])
            paises1.pop(a)

            while l<5:
                l+=1
                a = random.choice(range(len(paises1)))

                bolsa4.append(paises1[a])
                paises1.pop(a)

                while m<5:
                    m+=1
                    a = random.choice(range(len(paises1)))

                    bolsa5.append(paises1[a])
                    paises1.pop(a)

                    while n<5:
                        n+=1
                        a = random.choice(range(len(paises1)))

                        bolsa6.append(paises1[a])
                        paises1.pop(a)

                        while o<5:
                            o+=1
                            a = random.choice(range(len(paises1)))

                            bolsa7.append(paises1[a])
                            paises1.pop(a)


print()
print('GRUPO A\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(bolsa1[0],bolsa1[1],bolsa1[2],bolsa1[3]))
print('GRUPO B\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(bolsa2[0],bolsa2[1],bolsa2[2],bolsa2[3]))
print('GRUPO C\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(bolsa3[0],bolsa3[1],bolsa3[2],bolsa3[3]))
print('GRUPO D\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(bolsa4[0],bolsa4[1],bolsa4[2],bolsa4[3]))
print('GRUPO E\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(bolsa5[0],bolsa5[1],bolsa5[2],bolsa5[3]))
print('GRUPO F\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(bolsa6[0],bolsa6[1],bolsa6[2],bolsa6[3]))
print('GRUPO G\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(bolsa7[0],bolsa7[1],bolsa7[2],bolsa7[3]))
print('GRUPO H\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(paises1[0],paises1[1],paises1[2],paises1[3]))
```

Espero me puedan asistir.
Ademas de lo solicitado, si tambien tiene otra idea mejor para hacer la seleccion random de los equipos por favor publiquenlo tambien

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cosa puede simplificarse enormemente si usas código más "pythónico". Estas serían las ideas:

1. Para crear los grupos, basta "barajar" la lista inicial de paises y después tomar grupos de 4 de la lista barajada.
2. El resultado (los grupos) mejor meterlos en una lista, cuyos elementos serían a su vez listas (las bolsas), en vez de usar variables separadas llamadas `bolsa1`, `bolsa2`, etc. Esto permite hacer bucles (o comprensiones de listas) en vez de código tan largo y repetitivo
3. Para imprimirlos "tabuladamente" puedes usar `str.format()` y una cadena de formato que especifique el ancho, de modo que al imprimir todos los equipos ocupen el mismo ancho (el resto lo rellenará con espacios) y así salgan bien alineados verticalmente.

Estas son las ideas puestas en práctica:

```
import random

paises1 =[
  'Rusia', 'Egipto', 'Arabia Saudí', 'Uruguay', 'Portugal', 'España', 'Marruecos', 'Irán',
  'Francia', 'Australia', 'Perú', 'Dinamarca', 'Argentina', 'Islandia', 'Croacia',
  'Nigeria', 'Brasil', 'Suiza', 'Costa Rica', 'Serbia', 'Alemania', 'México',
  'Suecia', 'Corea del Sur', 'Bélgica', 'Panamá', 'Túnez', 'Inglaterra', 'Polonia',
  'Senegal', 'Colombia','Japón'
]

# El sorteo son dos líneas
random.shuffle(paises1)
bolsas = [ paises1[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(paises1),4) ]

# Y ahora a imprimir el resultado
plantilla = "{:15}"*8
print(plantilla.format(*("Grupo "+letra for letra in "ABCDEFGH")))
print(plantilla.format(*["--------"]*8))

for fila in zip(*bolsas):
  print(plantilla.format(*fila))
```

Resultado:

```
Grupo A        Grupo B        Grupo C        Grupo D        Grupo E        Grupo F        Grupo G        Grupo H        
--------       --------       --------       --------       --------       --------       --------       --------       
Uruguay        Nigeria        Senegal        Egipto         Corea del Sur  Alemania       Brasil         Japón          
Portugal       Arabia Saudí   Rusia          Australia      Dinamarca      Serbia         Panamá         Inglaterra     
Túnez          Suecia         Argentina      Irán           Costa Rica     España         Bélgica        Suiza          
Croacia        Islandia       Francia        Marruecos      Perú           Polonia        Colombia       México
```

## Explicación

#### Sorteo

El sorteo se hace en dos líneas. ¿Cómo funciona?

```
random.shuffle(paises1)
```

Desordena la lista de paises dejándolos en un orden aleatorio, diferente cada vez.

```
[ paises[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(paises1), 4) ]
```

es lo que se llama una *comprension de listas*. Genera una lista al iterar en el bucle `for` que lleva dentro. Este bucle va variando el valor de `i` (de 4 en 4 empezando en 0, por lo que `i` irá tomando los valores, 0, 4, 8, etc.) Para cada valor de `i` se evalúa la expresión `paises1[i:i+4]` y el resultado se añade a la lista que se está construyendo. `paises1[i:i+4]` toma una rodaja de cuatro elementos de la lista previamente barajada. En la primera iteración será la rodaja `[0:4]`, en la siguiente será `[4:8]`, etc. Es decir, vamos sacando los elementos de la lista barajada de 4 en 4. Cada una de estas rodajas es otra "lista" (de 4 elementos), por lo que el resultado final será una lista de listas. Tendrá tantas sub-listas como bolsas se hayan creado (8 en este caso) y cada sublista tiene 4 elementos que son 4 países al azar.

Por ejemplo el resultado podría ser esta lista de listas:

```
[['Uruguay', 'Portugal', 'Túnez', 'Croacia'],
 ['Nigeria', 'Arabia Saudí', 'Suecia', 'Islandia'],
 ['Senegal', 'Rusia', 'Argentina', 'Francia'],
 ['Egipto', 'Australia', 'Irán', 'Marruecos'],
 ['Corea del Sur', 'Dinamarca', 'Costa Rica', 'Perú'],
 ['Alemania', 'Serbia', 'España', 'Polonia'],
 ['Brasil', 'Panamá', 'Bélgica', 'Colombia'],
 ['Japón', 'Inglaterra', 'Suiza', 'México']]
```

#### Impresión

Necesitamos imprimir los 8 grupos formados, en 8 columnas. Creamos una plantilla mediante:

```
plantilla = "{:15}"*8
```

La variable `plantilla` contiene una cadena de formato. Usa la expresión `{:15}` repetida ocho veces. Cuando se use junto con `format()` se esperarán ocho valores, que irán a parar a cada uno de los `{}`. El 15 es el ancho (en caracteres) con que se imprimirá ese valor. Si tiene menos de 15, se rellenará con espacios por la derecha (si tuviera más, se imprimirán todos, no se recortan, y eso estropearía la tabla; debes asegurarte de que ningún país ocupa más de 15 letras, o mejor de 13 para que haya separación entre columnas).

```
print(plantilla.format(*["Grupo "+letra for letra in "ABCDEFGH"]))
print(plantilla.format(*["--------"]*8))
```

Se usa esa plantilla para imprimir los títulos de las columnas usando `format`. A ese `format` hay que pasarle ocho parámetros y ya que todos son parecidos, uso una comprensión de listas otra vez para crear los ocho elementos que serán las cadenas `"Grupo A"`, `"Grupo B"`, etc. Poniendo un `*` delante de la lista así formada hacemos que se *desempaquete* y sus elementos separados se conviertan en los ocho parámetros que `format()` recibirá.

De forma análoga usamos `format()` una segunda vez para imprimir ocho veces la ristra de guiones que subraya el título de las columnas.

Finalmente llegamos a la parte más farragosa. Hay que imprimir los grupos, pero "en vertical". Ya que cada elemento de la variable `bolsas` es un grupo con cuatro equipos, lo que necesitamos es "transponer" esa lista, de modo que en lugar de tener ocho grupos con cuatro elementos cada uno, tenga cuatro listas (las cuatro filas de la tabla) con ocho elementos cada una (correspondientes a las ocho columnas).

En álgebra diríamos que si `bolsas` es una matriz de 8x4, necesitamos convertirla en su *transpuesta*, de 4x8.

Esto puede hacerse en Python con el truco `transpuesta = zip(*lista)`. No voy a entrar en detalles de cómo funciona, pero lo usamos así:

```
for fila in zip(*bolsas):
  print(plantilla.format(*fila))
```

El bucle itera (cuatro veces) por cada una de las filas de la transpuesta. En cada iteración la variable `fila` contiene los ocho elementos a mostrar en esa fila. Simplemente se desempaquetan usando de nuevo el asterisco para convertirlo en los ocho parámetros que `plantilla.format()` necesita.

Answer (score 0):

...yo iba a poner esta respuesta:

```
import pandas as pd

D1 = {'Grupo A':bolsa1,'Grupo B':bolsa2,'Grupo C':bolsa3,'Grupo D':bolsa4}

D2 = {'Grupo E':bolsa5,'Grupo F':bolsa6,'Grupo G':bolsa7,'Grupo H':paises1}

print(pd.DataFrame(D1,index = ['','','','','']))
time.sleep(2)
print()
print(pd.DataFrame(D2,index = ['','','','','']))
```

en esta variante falta la alineacion a la derecha...pues por default la ubica a la izquierda